# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'tuple' [python pandas]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, pycharm

This is probably simple but my amateur skills are shining through. PyCharm is giving me an error from the `if pow(2,64) < pid < 0:` line stating:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'tuple'

```
def int_checker_projects(columnName):
    intArray = []
    for value in projectsFileData[columnName]:
        try:
            intArray.append(int(value))
        except ValueError:
            sys.exit("ERROR: {0} in the {1} column is not an integer. Terminating Program.".format(value, columnName))
    return intArray

projectIDs = int_checker_projects('projectID')

for pid in zip(projectIDs):
    if pow(2, 64) < pid < 0:
        sys.exit("ERROR: projectID {0} must be an integer greater than zero and less than 2^64.".format(pid))
```

I realize I should put that line into the int_checker function, but lets worry about the error first :)

Comment: can you `print(projectIDs)`?

Comment: I reckon pid is a tuple indeed, try 'pid,' (add comma to the end)

Comment: @RichieV print(projectsIDs) prints..... [11, 2, 10, -1, 100]
...and Kaiyaha, that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `zip()`, it just turns every element of `projectIDs` into a tuple. Try this:

```py
for pid in projectIDs:
    if pow(2, 64) < pid < 0:
        sys.exit("ERROR: projectID {0} must be an integer greater than zero and less than 2^64.".format(pid))
```

Comment: Interesting. I removed the zip and it got rid of the error, BUT it did not detect the value '-1' in my array. when I do print(projectsIDs), it prints..... [11, 2, 10, -1, 100] ...why did that happen?

Comment: @blindside044 Because `pow(2, 64)` is a positive integer. The `pow(2, 64) < pid < 0` basically asks for an integer which is greater than 18446744073709551616 **and** smaller than 0. There's no such integer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare a tuple and an integer. The `zip()` function creates a zip object which gives you n-sized tuples when is being iterated through, and *n* is the number of zip() arguments. You need to unpack each tuple before comparing with an integer. If you want to compare with each of the integers, do this:

```
for pid in zip(projectIDs):
    for ID in pid:
        if pow(2, 64) < pid < 0:
            sys.exit("ERROR: projectID {0} must be an integer greater than zero and less than 2^64.".format(pid))
```

If you expect your tuple to only have one element, there is no sense of using zip at all, but yet you can do it like this as well:

```
for pid, in zip(projectIDs):        
    if pow(2, 64) < pid < 0:
        sys.exit("ERROR: projectID {0} must be an integer greater than zero and less than 2^64.".format(pid))
```

Or if you only want to compare with the first element of each tuple:

```
for pid, *_ in zip(projectIDs):
    if pow(2, 64) < pid < 0:
        sys.exit("ERROR: projectID {0} must be an integer greater than zero and less than 2^64.".format(pid))
```